# Access Query Makes Linked Table Local

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query in access that pools data from several linked tables. I've noticed that, when the query gets ran, it removes the link to a specific table, "SPAFTable", and seemingly converts the linked table to a local table.

I'm not exactly sure what's causing this, since this is simply a SELECT query that involves no table creation explicitly defined in the query. Here is the query itself:

```
SELECT SPAFTable.Enrolled_Class, SPAFTable.Last_Name, SPAFTable.BarCode1, SPAFTable.BarCode2, SPAFTable.BarCode3, SPAFTable.BarCode4, SPAFTable.Guard1_Cell, SPAFTable.Guard2_Cell, SPAFTable.Guard1_Rel, SPAFTable.Guard2_Rel, SPAFTable.Auth1_Cell, SPAFTable.Auth2_Cell, SPAFTable.Auth3_Cell, SPAFTable.Auth4_Cell, SPAFTable.Auth1_Rel, SPAFTable.Auth2_Rel, SPAFTable.Auth3_Rel, SPAFTable.Auth4_Rel, SPAFTable.First_Name, SPAFTable.Student_Nbr, SPAFTable.Street_Address, SPAFTable.Apt_Nbr, SPAFTable.City, SPAFTable.State, SPAFTable.Zip, SPAFTable.Guard1_Restr, SPAFTable.Guard2_Restr, SPAFTable.Auth1_Restr, SPAFTable.Auth2_Restr, SPAFTable.Auth3_Restr, SPAFTable.Auth4_Restr, SPAFTable.StudentName, SPAFTable.HomePhone, SPAFTable.RInd, Student_T.[Student Photo], Family_T.DL_Pic_Location AS Guard1_DLPic, Family_T_1.DL_Pic_Location AS Guard2_DLPic, Family_T_2.Drivers_License_attach AS Auth1_DLPic, Family_T_3.Drivers_License_attach AS Auth2_DLPic, Family_T_4.Drivers_License_attach AS Auth3_DLPic, Family_T_5.Drivers_License_attach AS Auth4_DLPic, Student_T.Student_Pic_Location
FROM (((((Family_T RIGHT JOIN (SPAFTable LEFT JOIN Student_T ON SPAFTable.Student_Nbr = Student_T.Student_Nbr) ON Family_T.Family_Member_Nbr = SPAFTable.Guard1) LEFT JOIN Family_T AS Family_T_1 ON SPAFTable.Guard2 = Family_T_1.Family_Member_Nbr) LEFT JOIN Family_T AS Family_T_2 ON SPAFTable.Auth1 = Family_T_2.Family_Member_Nbr) LEFT JOIN Family_T AS Family_T_3 ON SPAFTable.Auth2 = Family_T_3.Family_Member_Nbr) LEFT JOIN Family_T AS Family_T_4 ON SPAFTable.Auth3 = Family_T_4.Family_Member_Nbr) LEFT JOIN Family_T AS Family_T_5 ON SPAFTable.Auth4 = Family_T_5.Family_Member_Nbr;
```

Anybody have any ideas as to why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can not be done by the simple select query. You may have done something in your VBA code ?

Comment: I'm inheriting this project...the code is quite complex. Sounds like I'll be doing some extensive digging?

Comment: Yes, the problem is not here. The causes are multiple: you table may be created automatically at each startup, by a VBA call on pressing a button, calling a macro... Search in the whole project VBA code the string SPAFTable to see how it is modified.

Comment: Just what I feared...this isn't done through VBA, but must be through Access utilities, like Macros, somehow. The previous programmer mixed his approach between VBA and Access tools.

Comment: Pure VBA is better... Access Macros can be replaced by VBA functions/subroutines.